# Check box to select all check boxes in a gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I made this simple code to check all `checkboxes` in a `gridview`

```
function chkFun() {
        if ($("#chkSelectAll").is(':checked')) {
            $("#grdSearchResults tr").each(function () {
                debugger
                var checkBox = $(this).find("input[id*='chkSelected']");
                $(checkBox).attr("checked", true);
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#grdSearchResults tr").each(function () {
                debugger
                var checkBox = $(this).find("input[id*='chkSelected']");
                $(checkBox).attr("checked", false);
            });
        }
    }
```

`chkFun` will called in the `chkAll` `checkbox` `OnClicking`.. and it is working fine in the 1st time [selecting & deselecting] .. after that it is not working at all and i don't know why.

I tried to debugg it as u see in code it go right in everywhere .. but this line `$(checkBox).attr("checked", false);` is not doing any thing after the first time

Comment: Can you please provide your markup? it's kinda hard going by your JS code only.

Comment: try to use class instead of id

Answer (score 4):

Use `.prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
function chkFun() {
    if ($("#chkSelectAll").is(':checked')) {
        $("#grdSearchResults tr").find("input[id*='chkSelected']").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#grdSearchResults tr").find("input[id*='chkSelected']").prop('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Also you don't need to use `.each()`, you could select all with one line

Or you could bind the function to `chkSelectAll` and use the code Satpal recommended in the comments to make the code even shorter

```
$('#chkSelectAll').on('change', function () {
    $("#grdSearchResults tr").find("input[id*='chkSelected']").prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

Comment: Ok, `.prop()` works fine .. can you explain the reason why `.attr()` wasn't a good function here ??

Comment: .attr doesn't work with boleean values @Mahmoud There's a good post here explaining prop vs attr http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/1696560

Comment: if block can be removed and code can be improved with `$("#grdSearchResults tr").find("input[id*='chkSelected']").prop('checked', this.checked)`

Comment: @Satpal i just noticed, this.checked won't work because `this` is not scoped into the function so this.checked wont work :/